# How do I add a variable as a column value in a result set?

Tags: powershell, variables, active-directory, select-object, group-membership

I have a variable that loops through values from a CSV file. As the loop returns result sets for each value I have in the CSV, I also want that value (the variable) returned in the result set. I tried to add my variable, `$user`, in my `Select` statement, but it just shows in the column header and my value is either blank or `{}`.

Here's the loop code:

```bsh
$users = Get-Content C:\AD\ad_groups.txt

ForEach ($User in $users) 
{
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $user  -Server MyServerName| Select name,SamAccountName,$user 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to use what's called a calculated property. In place of $User, try the following hash table as a property value. "Name" can be shortened to "N" and "Expression to "E" (without the double quotes as seen here), if you feel it's necessary/preferred.

```
@{Name='User';Expression={$User}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a calculated property like this:

```
$userList = Get-Content C:\AD\ad_groups.txt
ForEach ($User in $userList) { 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $user -Server MyServerName | 
        Select-Object name, SamAccountName, @{Name='user';Expression={$User}} 
}
```

Comment: Yep, that returned exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be only a handful of characters away from working.

You don't say what the format is of `$User`, but since it's something acceptable to the `-Identity` parameter that means, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember), it must be one of the following (links to [output object](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adprincipal) property mine, interleaved with the code to select that value)...

> [Distinguished Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject.distinguishedname)
>
> Example:
>   CN=saradavisreports,OU=europe,CN=users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $user  -Server MyServerName| Select name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
```

> [GUID (objectGUID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject.objectguid)
>
> Example: 599c3d2e-f72d-4d20-8a88-030d99495f20

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $user  -Server MyServerName| Select name,SamAccountName,objectGUID
```

> [Security Identifier (objectSid)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adprincipal.sid)
>
> Example: S-1-5-21-3165297888-301567370-576410423-1103

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $user  -Server MyServerName| Select name,SamAccountName,objectSid
```

> [Security Accounts Manager (SAM) Account Name (sAMAccountName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adprincipal.samaccountname)
>
> Example: saradavisreports

(`sAMAccountName` property already selected in original code)

If `$users` contains identifiers in multiple formats, or you want to retain the exact text passed to `Get-ADGroupMember`, then you will need to use one of the other answers to select it as a property using a `ScriptBlock`.